# JQuery / Javascript Draggable and Resizable don't work with a div clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm currently trying to make an html page to organize some widgets that I clone and move with JQuery Draggable to place them in a div Droppable.

So, my problem is that I want to resize a div when it is in the Droppable div (the cloned one). But it doesn't work. I can only resize the div when it is in initial position.

I've trying a lot of things like this but the problem is still the same.

```
$('.widget').resizable().draggable({
  //containment: "#seizeNeufDroppable",
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  revert: true
});
```

Here my code at JSFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/ukoeb65g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is six month now, You probably found your answer, but may be other folks need help on this one.
I changed your code, tried to make it simple, like, you don't need:

```
revert: true
```

Anyway Here is an 
[update of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukoeb65g/3/).